# Angular 6 routing in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.1

I created asp.net core 2.1 application with angular 6, and it's running fine by IISExpress. But after I published, all compiled css and js files can't be loaded due to bad path.

The startup page is index.html:

Source code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WebApplication2</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

After published:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WebApplication2</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.7fa1a6c91a163e80323b.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.4853e6859e98ef4b710a.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.9fd6ccea546c33575aa9.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

If I manually modify base href in index.html, all css and js files are loaded, but not functioning.

I think there should be setting for this to enable both development and production working. Any idea?

Edit:

It turns out that manually modifying base href is the way to fix it. It should be changed to absolute URL path. I changed it to "appPath/" before but it broke angular routing. If I change it to "https://www.server.com/appPath/", it works well.

I'd think there is the best way to pass the correct base URL to index.html, like passing "@Url.Content("~/")" from Razor layout. But need to figure out how to do it.

Comment: We'd need to see your project settings to be able to do more than just guess.

Comment: Thank you, @fredrik. I am not so familiar with asp.net core application structure. There are many json settings in project, like appsettings.json, angular.json, tsconfig.json, etc. Let me figure out how to upload zipped project here.

Comment: You don't upload zipped projects here - there's a specific close vote that everything is to be included in the question itself. What we probably need are the `project.json` (npm package file) and `.csproj` files.

Comment: Plz also check GitHub for source code: https://github.com/jasonmdli/asp.net_core_2.1_angular_6.